# Postgres translate trigger into rule/ help optimize trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, partitioning

I had to partition our database for performance. However inserts slowed down by 2-3 times.

We do insert a lot of data in one query, and what I read the trigger is run for every row but a rule is only run every query. This is what I suspect is the issue.

I'm not even sure this is possible to do in rules.
So I need help either optimizing this trigger or to translate it into a rule.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
      DECLARE
        partition_date TEXT;
        partition TEXT;

      BEGIN
        partition_date := to_char((SELECT time from timestamps where ID=NEW.timestamp_id),'YYYY_MM_DD');
        partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_date;
        IF to_regclass(partition) IS NULL THEN
          RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
          EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition ||'(
            timestamp_id integer references timestamps(id),
            channel_id integer references channels(id)
          ) INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME || ');';
          EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || partition ||'_timestamp_id_index ON ' || partition || ' (timestamp_id);';
          EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || partition ||'_channel_id_index ON ' || partition || ' (channel_id);';
        END IF;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT ($1).*;' USING NEW;

        RETURN NULL;
      END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
  "
```

Comment: For a bridge-table,  `{timestamp_id, channel_id}` will be the natural key. The fields also could be NOT NULL, and a supporting (unique) index `{channel_id, timestamp_id}` should also be present.

Comment: The second select from the `timestamps` table seems unnecessary and can be replaced with `partition_date := to_char(index_date, ,'YYYY_MM_DD');` - but that will not make a big difference

Comment: Do you have an index on `timestamps.id`? Variable `index_date` isn't used anywhere so it can be easily removed. And take a look at the syntax like `CREATE TABLE ... (LIKE ... INCLUDNIG INDEXES)` (that won't make trigger work faster but will make it more readable).

Comment: @IldarMusin yeah I did an optimization and forgot to fully change it here, that variable is gone. Thanks for the tip! Any idea if it's possible to make it into a rule instead?